# Resolving many to many relationship MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

I have 3 tables,

users(id) , userproduct (user_id,product_id) and product (id).

When a user adds a product their user_id and the product_id is saved in USERPRODUCT table.

Now at the same time another user can save a product (kind of like "set as favorite") for this I need to save the user_id of the user who saved it and the product_id of the product. This will create another table (call it favorites) however this table is also a resolve to the many to many relationship between "users" table and "product" table.

the question: is it possible for this, to have 2 tables resolving a many to many relationship or is there any other way to solve my issue.

if it is possible how will one be draw this in the ER diagram

Comment: Do you create a new table every time a different user favourites a product?

I think you need the three tables you have, but I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: noo a new table will not be created every time @David I meant that there will exist another table called favorites where the user ID of the logged in user and product ID of the product will be saved.

Comment: But you already have "userproduct". Can't you use it?

Comment: this is were the issue comes. in the USERPRODUCT table the user_id of the user that uploads their product is saved. any other user with different user_id can save their product which should then be saved in their Account settings as "Favorite products" I hope you  understand what I mean @David

Comment: I have solved it by adding new rows of user_id and product_id and adding a new attribute to userproduct table called "favorites". thank you anyways @David

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want.
you may use only one table and design your relations with boolean fields
USERS(id)
PRODUCTS(id)
USERPROD(userid, productid, isbought, isfavorite, isowned)

or you may use one many-to-many support table for every relation is up to you

maybe you want another field "owner" in PRODUCTS table to store the user id. this is a one-to-one relation

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is actually describe the kind of relation between user and product: a favorite, or he 'owns' it.
Just add another field to the `userproduct`-table defining the relation: `favorite` or `owned`